# UIPopover changes background color

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

[image]I have a UIPopoverCOntroller which am presenting on tap of bar buttom item, and i have a textview inside that popover when ever am tapping on textview am animating the view's y by -300 then background color of view gets changed to clear color.i tried setting background color on completion of animation but no luck, anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Exactly what you want?

Comment: i dont want my background view color getting changed

Comment: can you add a screen shot?

Comment: Just added screenshot, my popover background color getting changed to clear color